# Write a loop and iterate each children element using js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an object below. I need to write a for loop which iterates every children
and display ID.

I used underscore library but didn't found solution

```
   *[  
   {  
      Id:1,
      Name:"Test",
      children:[  
         {  
            Id:11,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  
               {  
                  Id:113,
                  Name:"Test",
                  children:[  

                  ]
               },
               {  
                  Id:114,
                  Name:"Test",
                  children:[  

                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            Id:12,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  

            ]
         },
         {  
            Id:13,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  
               {  
                  Id:115,
                  Name:"Test",
                  children:[  
                     {  
                        Id:1111,
                        Name:"Test",
                        children:[  

                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            Id:14,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  

            ]
         }
      ]
   }   {  
      Id:2,
      Name:"Test",
      children:[  

      ]
   }
]*
```

Comment: Please show the actual code which you tried. We can help you fix that.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: need to display each `ID` from the above object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it resursively:

```js
var items= [  
   {  
      Id:1,
      Name:"Test",
      children:[  
         {  
            Id:11,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  
               {  
                  Id:113,
                  Name:"Test",
                  children:[  

                  ]
               },
               {  
                  Id:114,
                  Name:"Test",
                  children:[  

                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            Id:12,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  

            ]
         },
         {  
            Id:13,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  
               {  
                  Id:115,
                  Name:"Test",
                  children:[  
                     {  
                        Id:1111,
                        Name:"Test",
                        children:[  

                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            Id:14,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  

            ]
         }
      ]
   },   {  
      Id:2,
      Name:"Test",
      children:[  

      ]
   }
];

displayIds(items);

function displayIds(datas) {
  datas.forEach(function(data) {
    console.log(data.Id);
    if (data.children) {
      displayIds(data.children);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I need code in JS 5. Currently my application works in ECMA 5

Comment: could you please tell how to find parent object. i.e. if I have 115 I need to know the parent of it

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = [  
   {  
      Id:1,
      Name:"Test",
      children:[  
         {  
            Id:11,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  
               {  
                  Id:113,
                  Name:"Test",
                  children:[  

                  ]
               },
               {  
                  Id:114,
                  Name:"Test",
                  children:[  

                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            Id:12,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  

            ]
         },
         {  
            Id:13,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  
               {  
                  Id:115,
                  Name:"Test",
                  children:[  
                     {  
                        Id:1111,
                        Name:"Test",
                        children:[  

                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            Id:14,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  

            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      Id:2,
      Name:"Test",
      children:[  

      ]
   }
];

showId(data);

function showId(data){
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  console.log(data[i].Id);
  if(data[i].children.length > 0){
    showId(data[i].children);
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive for this like

```js
var obj = [  
   {  
      Id:1,
      Name:"Test",
      children:[  
         {  
            Id:11,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  
               {  
                  Id:113,
                  Name:"Test",
                  children:[  

                  ]
               },
               {  
                  Id:114,
                  Name:"Test",
                  children:[  

                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            Id:12,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  

            ]
         },
         {  
            Id:13,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  
               {  
                  Id:115,
                  Name:"Test",
                  children:[  
                     {  
                        Id:1111,
                        Name:"Test",
                        children:[  

                        ]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            Id:14,
            Name:"Test",
            children:[  

            ]
         }
      ]
   },   {  
      Id:2,
      Name:"Test",
      children:[  

      ]
   }
]

function showIds(obj, i=0) {
  if(!obj[i]) return
  console.log(obj[i].Id);
  showIds(obj, i+1)
  if(obj[i].children) showIds(obj[i].children);
}

showIds(obj)
```